# Access Validation Error?

Tags: ms-access

Hi all I'm creating a database in Microsoft Access 2007 that involves the Date Of Birth and Age of the customer in one particular form. I have already managed to use a validation rule that restricts and age limit so the customer must be 17 or over; but i also need to calculate age from the DOB and when using this piece of validation http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/calculating-age-from-a-birth-date-in-access-HA001055071.aspx if gives me the error: "SQL Syntax coloumn error" or something along them lines. I think it could be the two pieces of code interfereing with each other. When i get back to my computer with access installed i will post the exact error and other piece of validation.

Can anyone help me?

---

Here is the validation in the DOB field:

```
 <=DateSerial(Year(Date())-17,Month(Date()),Day(Date()))
```

and here is the validation i am trying to put into the Age field:

```
=DateDiff("yyyy", [DOB], Now())+ Int( Format(now(), "mmdd") < Format( [DOB], "mmdd") )
```

And this is the error i am recieving:

```
"Invalid SQL Syntax - cannot use multiple coloumns in a coloumn-level CHECK constraint"
```

Anyideas?

Comment: Sure. I'll give it a shot after you post the code.

Comment: I have added text from additional information posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line:

```
=DateDiff("yyyy", [DOB], Now())+ Int( Format(now(), "mmdd") < Format( [DOB], "mmdd") )
```

As the Control Source for the age field, which should **not** be bound to a control in your query or table.

Comment: Why `Now()` instead of `Date()`? I've never seen a database that records both time and date of birth...

Comment: @David-W-Fenton It also does not make any difference. BTW a maternity database would record time and date of birth. I can think of others.

Comment: If the field is named Date of Birth and includes a time part, then it's misnamed.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - You are such a stickler. But I love ya for it. =)

Comment: I have been fighting against inappropriate use of Now() for ages. It's all over the Access documentation and the form and report wizards and it drives me crazy. When I see `Format(Now(), "Short Date")` I want to scream. Sometimes I actually do.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I am not prepared to fight against the volume of documentation that uses Now() and I find it tedious at this stage to constantly replace Now() with Date() and then have to explain. Please do not not make me have to explain why I have *not* replaced Now() with Date(). I am a very slow typist.